# How to set Maximum bit rate

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia-graphics-card

I want to know how to set Maximum bit rate on my ffmpeg command.

I'm using nvenc and for some reason -maxrate shows when coding, but no when I check with mediainfo the output.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: "for some reason -maxrate shows when coding" – where? Please share the command line output.

Answer (score 1):

`-maxrate` does specify the maximum bitrate. Note that its specific meaning changes depending on the encoder and the other settings with which it is used. You typically want to use `-maxrate` in combination with a specific target bitrate setting (`-b:v`) in a variable bitrate encoding mode, thus setting `-rc vbr`, too.

You will not be able to see your `-maxrate` settings in your output file or its metadata, as this parameter simply controls the encoder's rate control; the decoder will not particularly care about the maximum bitrate used.